# Send Data to View Controller of choice

Tags: objective-c, authentication, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to perform something that I know is very simple, yet I am not sure of the syntax.

First, I get the user to input Facebook login info, which signs them in. My code then pulls their profile picture, username, email, and the Facebook button and displays it in "LoginiewController". The prof pic is a view controller called **profilePicture**, the username is called **lblUsername**, email is **lblEmail**, and the FB button is called **loginButton**.

**ALL** I want to do is write some code that sends these 4 values to a ProfileViewController, which is not the next view controller by segue, so that it displays the profile picture, username, email and * *logout* * button. Below is my code for the LoginViewController:

***FYI, the code shows an initial view of just a FB login button, Regular login button, and a sign up button, with the profile picture view, username, and email hidden to start. Once logged in, I have the same view controller now show the profile picture, username, and email, with hiding which ever login button was *not *clicked.

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NOLogin.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
    [NOLogin.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    [NOLogin.layer setShadowOpacity:0.1];
    [NOLogin.layer setShadowRadius:0.2];
    [NOLogin.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.1)];
    [NOLogin.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    [NOLogin.layer setBorderWidth:0.1f];

    self.loginButton.delegate = self;
    [self toggleHiddenState:YES];
    _signUp.hidden = NO;
    NOLogin.hidden = NO;
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"";
    self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
   // self.

}

-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"";

    [self toggleHiddenState:NO];
    [self toggleUnhiddenState:YES];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *tabcontroller = (UITabBarController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabController"];
    [self presentModalViewController:tabcontroller animated:YES];



}

-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user{
    NSLog(@"%@", user);
    self.profilePicture.profileID = user.objectID;
    self.lblUsername.text = user.name;
    self.lblEmail.text = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
}

-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"";
    [self toggleHiddenState:YES];
    _signUp.hidden = NO;
    NOLogin.hidden = NO;

}


-(void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}


-(void)toggleHiddenState:(BOOL)shouldHide{
    self.lblUsername.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.lblEmail.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.profilePicture.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.begin.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.loggedinwallpaper.hidden = shouldHide;

}

-(void)toggleUnhiddenState:(BOOL)shouldShow{
    _signUp.hidden = YES;
    NOLogin.hidden = YES;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)unwindToLogin:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {

}




#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
/*- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    [segue destinationTabBabController]
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}


- (IBAction)j:(id)sender {
}*/
- (IBAction)enter:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have initialised the ViewController you want to present, you can now access its' properties (those you've mentioned and assign to them the values you want).

```
-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"";

[self toggleHiddenState:NO];
[self toggleUnhiddenState:YES];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UITabBarController *tabcontroller = (UITabBarController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabController"];
//Get the first controller that will be displayed (could be of a different index, depends on how you set it up)
UIViewController *firstController = [[((UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController) viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];//Modify UIViewController to your View controller class name... 
//Now set the properties of that controller to the info you need. I've added one, please continue with the others...
firstController.lblUsername = self.lblUsername;
//Finally, present the tabController.
[self presentModalViewController:tabcontroller animated:YES];
}
```